# Error in matlab code for declaring a variable and then using it

Tags: matlab, variables, scope, machine-learning, matlab-figure

Declaring a variable (`filename`) in line 2 and using it in line 4 gives error.
If I give use `data.temp(12,;)` then it runs fine but if i give `filename = temp` and `index = 12` as an input and then run `data.filename(index,:);` ,it gives an error. Somebody please help me out here
Here is the exact code:

```
data = importdata('check.mat');
filename = input('Enter the filename: ','s'); 
index = input('Enter Index of the file: '); 
row = data.filename(index,:);
```

> Reference to non-existent field 'filename'

Comment: Reference to non-existent field 'filename'.

Comment: there you have it, data.filename does not exist

Comment: data.filename does not exist but data.temp exist and i have initialised filename = temp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using structs wrongly.

When accessing a structure using a string, you need to use [`getfield`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html), because `fieldname` contains a string, but when you do `data.fieldname` you are not actually using the value of `fieldname` in after the point, but actually triying to access the field `fieldname` in data, which doesn't exist.

Instead do:

```
row=getfield(data, filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. why was previous code not working on variable name but was working on variable value.

Comment: @user3778989 because `data.fieldname` was triying to access something called `fieldname` inside data, it was not replacing `fieldname` by `temp` and then trying to access  `data.temp`. If this helped, consider accepting the asnwer as valid (green tick next to my answer)

Comment: Would `data.(fieldname(index,:))` also work here?  I'm not sure about the performance, but I do like dynamic field references oh so much.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Not sure, as fieldname is a string, would that index the string, instead of the data?

Comment: Oh, the OP wants to index the data in the field? (For some reason I thought it was a character array.)  In that case, the input should be `data.(fieldname)(index,:)`, which I've found valid since I started using it a few years ago (not sure how far back it extends).

Comment: @TroyHaskin nice! didnt know that you could do that! Consider adding it as an answer!

Comment: Noted. :)  Thought you're still not wrong here: +1.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`getfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html), you can also use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) that, in the recent versions of Matlab I've used, permit direct indexing of the referenced field:

```
stuff = data.(filename)(index,:);
```

The sub-expression `data.(filename)` resolves to the data in the field `filename` of the `data` struct and `(index,:)` then indexes that data.